# SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 - Accessibility Guidlelines

Tags: reporting-services, accessibility

Does anyone know if the html output from SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 is accessible in terms of the WCAG 1.0 or 2.0

Comment: Judging from the scary HTML I've seen coming out of some Microsoft tools, I'd be surprised, because it doesn't seem to be a priority for them. But hey, here's to wishful thinking..

Comment: I had a look. Its scary.

Answer (score 1):

Not even close